# jQuery: get previous tag, nesting problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to get the previous tag from $('#marker').prevAll("span.curPos:eq(1)");

Problem is that the HTML might look like:

```
<span class="curPos">some text</span><em><span class="curPos">more</span></em>
<div id="marker">bla</div>
<span class="curPos">... text</span>
```

And all methods I've tried in order to get the previous span element with class="curPos" seems to ignore the span-tag if it's inside some other tag, like em.

It will simply ignore everything in the nested EM tag and instead return the previous curPos before the EM.

Any idea how I can get the previous tag even if it's nested 1-n levels ?

--
edit:

all of this is wrapped in a container DIV, I would also prefer if it never looked outside this div - not reversing back any further than to that div/selector.

maybe there's a way to extract all HTML from between 2 selectors?  if so, I could solve it with regex and insert back?

script in action: http://jsfiddle.net/H6fvy/  (used to key track of "cursor")

Comment: HTML is tree like structure. Your sample doesn't have any sibling of the nested span. Then how you'll get previous tag? You have to code for this. `$('#marker').prevAll("em span.curPos:eq(1), span.curPos:eq(1)");`

Comment: Can the nearest previous "span.curPos" be not inside another element as well in your question? In other words if the <em><span class="curPos">more</span></em> was not there should the <span class="curPos">some text</span> be matched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, `prevAll()` only checks the siblings so that makes sense that anything nested isn't matched.

Is it possible to embed the `<em>` within the `<span>` instead of the other way around?  This seems to me like a case where it might be better to alter the markup to more cleanly work with your scripts instead of trying to force the jQuery.

**EDIT**:
Ok, so changing the markup won't work, that's fine.  This is an interesting little problem actually.  Here's a solution that will work, but I still can't help think that there's a better approach out there.

Given your initial markup of

```
<span class="curPos">some text</span>
<em><span class="curPos">more</span></em>
<div id="marker">bla</div>
```

This script will select the closet previous element, regardless of nesting

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#marker').prevAll().each(function () {
            console.log('Looping...');

            var $this = $(this);
            var matchedText;

            if ($this.hasClass('curPos')) {
                matchedText = $this.text();
            }
            else {
                var nested = $this.find('.curPos');
                if (nested)
                    matchedText = nested.text();
            }

            if (matchedText) {
                console.log(matchedText);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've got some logging in there just to indicate that it does what it's supposed to.  It loops through all previous elements using `each()`, but bails on the loop as soon as it finds a match by using `return false;`  Hopefully this can be modified to suit your needs.  Best of luck.

Comment: unfortunatly, no.. the markup order is needed for all other dependent jquery code.

Comment: wow, looks great but does behave in a non-desired way if the nested tags include more than one span, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hTMD2/

Comment: managed to fix that by adding :last to the selector, like:
 http://jsfiddle.net/p2Xvp/

but i'm afraid i got another problem, if the #marker is inside one of the nested, how to get it to prevAll on parent?  i think i might be able to fix it myself though, so thanks!

Comment: my final solution with nesting working fine and also a getNext() function for going the other way:
http://jsfiddle.net/jDj9u/

Answer (score 0):

Try the selector

```
Span[class=curPos]
```

That should select all spans with that class.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine:

```
$('#marker').prev().css("background", "yellow")
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/U2ryA/

Comment: That's still acting on the <em> element, even though it *looks* like it's doing the right thing.

Comment: you'r not accessing the previous span with class curPos, instead you are accessing _any_ previous tag. in this case it's the em tag that gets the background color.

Comment: @Gary, @Chris - yep -- feel free to use the fiddle to test other options -- eg @Gary's answer shows the same result in the chrome debugger.